# Calling Cython cdef function from another file

Tags: python, cython

I would like to call a cdef function defined in one file, from another file. I do not want to change cdef function to a cpdef, but I am willing to change the second file.

File1 parameters.pyx

```
cdef class Parameters:
    cdef int myVal

    def __init__(self):
        self.myVal = 0

    cdef change_myVal(self):
        self.myVal = 3
```

File2 model.pyx

```
from parameters import Parameters

cpdef single_run():
    parameters = Parameters()
    parameters.change_myVal()
```

The error I get is: "AttributeError: 'parameters.Parameters' object has no attribute 'change_myVal'"

Comment: `change_myVal` is a `cdef` method, so it's not available in Python. You did `from parameters import Parameters`, which is a Python import. Use [`cimport`](https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html) with a [`parameters.pxd` interface file](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html) or [turn `cimport_from_pyx=True` on](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.cimport_from_pyx).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and the way I fixed it, which might be a hack was to add a function outside of the class definition that accepts an instance of the class, and `cimport` that function separately.  For whatever reason, `cimport`ing only the class (via `cimport_from_pyx`) did not do it in a way that I could access cdef methods from another file.  So in file1 parameters.pyx we have:

```
 cdef class Parameters:
    def int myVal

    def __init__(self):
        self.myVal = 0

    cdef change_myVal(self):
        self.myVal = 3

 cdef void change_PVal(Parameters P) noexcept nogil:
    P.change_myVal()
```

and in File2 model.pyx, we have

```
from parameters import Parameters
from parameters cimport Parameters, change_PVal

cpdef single_run():
    cdef Parameters parameters = Parameters()
    change_PVal(parameters)
```

Here we Python import the `Parameters` class, but we also `cimport` Parameters so that it is recognized as a Cython extension.  Then rather than using the `change_myVal` directly I access it via the `change_PVal` function exported as a separate function.  For some reason this works when calling the method of the `cimport`ed class raises an `AttributeError`.

Perhaps someone can explain why this happens, at least when using the `cimport_prom_pyx` compiler option.